# HTTP POST and GET using cURL in Linux

Tags: linux, web-services, curl

I have a server application written in ASP.NET on Windows that provides a web service.

How can I call the web service in Linux with cURL?

Comment: For building a curl command quickly I'm using this online tool: https://curlbuilder.com/

Answer (score 812):

*nix provides a nice little command which makes our lives a lot easier.

**GET:**

*with JSON:*

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET http://hostname/resource
```

*with XML:*

```
curl -H "Accept: application/xml" -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -X GET http://hostname/resource
```

**POST:**

*For posting data:*

```
curl --data "param1=value1&param2=value2" http://hostname/resource
```

*For file upload:*

```
curl --form "fileupload=@filename.txt" http://hostname/resource
```

*RESTful HTTP Post:*

```
curl -X POST -d @filename http://hostname/resource
```

*For logging into a site (auth):*

```
curl -d "username=admin&password=admin&submit=Login" --dump-header headers http://localhost/Login
curl -L -b headers http://localhost/
```

**Pretty-printing the curl results:**

*For JSON:*

If you use `npm` and `nodejs`, you can install `json` package by running this command:

```
npm install -g json
```

Usage:

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET http://hostname/resource | json
```

If you use `pip` and `python`, you can install `pjson` package by running this command:

```
pip install pjson
```

Usage:

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET http://hostname/resource | pjson
```

If you use Python 2.6+, json tool is bundled within.

Usage:

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET http://hostname/resource | python -m json.tool
```

If you use `gem` and `ruby`, you can install `colorful_json` package by running this command:

```
gem install colorful_json
```

Usage:

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET http://hostname/resource | cjson
```

If you use `apt-get` (aptitude package manager of your Linux distro), you can install `yajl-tools` package by running this command:

```
sudo apt-get install yajl-tools
```

Usage:

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET http://hostname/resource |  json_reformat
```

*For XML:*

If you use *nix with Debian/Gnome envrionment, install `libxml2-utils`:

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2-utils
```

Usage:

```
curl -H "Accept: application/xml" -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -X GET http://hostname/resource | xmllint --format -
```

or install `tidy`:

```
sudo apt-get install tidy
```

Usage:

```
curl -H "Accept: application/xml" -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -X GET http://hostname/resource | tidy -xml -i -
```

**Saving the curl response to a file**

```
curl http://hostname/resource >> /path/to/your/file
```

or

```
curl http://hostname/resource -o /path/to/your/file
```

For detailed description of the curl command, hit:

```
man curl
```

For details about options/switches of the curl command, hit:

```
curl -h
```

Comment: If you're redirecting to `less`, you might need to [add `-sS`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21109454/52499).

Comment: How can i get the response to put into another command line?

Comment: @emoleumassi see x-yuri's comment before yours; you should be able to pipe the return into another command, such as `less`.

Comment: Potentially better than the grep approach below is to pipe the results to [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

Comment: Linux? Well, wouldn't it be better to credit unix here?

Comment: @Steven2163712: Certainly!

Comment: On the `get` example, you may quote the whole url to avoid errors on params, e.g. `curl "http://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/ip-address/report?ip=8.8.8.8&apikey=1233456890"`

Comment: Guys can you look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47526927/how-to-test-curl-commands-which-are-in-seaprate-file-and-get-the-count-of-execut

Answer (score 60):

I think Amith Koujalgi is correct but also, in cases where the webservice responses are in JSON then it might be more useful to see the results in a clean JSON format instead of a very long string. Just add | grep }| python -mjson.tool  to the end of curl commands here is two examples:

**GET approach with JSON result**

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" http://someHostName/someEndpoint | grep }| python -mjson.tool
```

**POST approach with JSON result**

```
curl -X POST  -H "Accept: Application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://someHostName/someEndpoint -d '{"id":"IDVALUE","name":"Mike"}' | grep }| python -mjson.tool
```

[image]

Comment: What is grep supposed to be doing here? I use the following with the same result: `curl -s -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "http://${API_BASE_URL}${1}" | python -mjson.tool`