# POST data with curl

Tags: bash, curl

Bash n00b here..  I'm posting a file b64 encoded like this using curl:

```
$ cat file.txt | openssl base64 | curl --data @- myhost.com/api
```

Works good. I split the key/value on the server side, the entire message goes into the key, but that's ok I parse it out and convert to ascii etc.. on the server.

How can I append other key/values to the post?  Something like..

```
$ cat file.txt | openssl base64 | PREPEND "key=value1&key2&value2&btext=" | curl --data @- myhost.com/api
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTTP POST and GET using cURL in linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14978411/http-post-and-get-using-curl-in-linux)

Comment: Guys/gals - before you slap a duplicate on this..  This is a Bash question, not a Curl question and is not a basic question about how to POST in Curl, which is the article that's been cited, and is not answered in the other article.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create all of the input to curl in a subshell, like so:

```
(echo -n "key=value1&key2=value2&btext="; openssl base64 < file.txt) | curl --data @- myhost.com/api
```

This will execute `echo` and `openssl` after each other and pass concatenated output to `curl`.

Comment: You may use `echo -n` to prevent the newline between `btext=` and the base64 data.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of @-, you can use -F to post both your prepended keys and the base64 text.

```
curl -F key=value1 -F key2=value2 -F btext=$(openssl base64 < file.txt | tr -d "\n") myhost.com/api
```

In my testing, base64 won't be sent correctly unless you remove linebreaks, and neither -F nor @- will work for particularly large files (>~50kb?).

Comment: Can you give a description of that? Your answer is currently incomplete.

Comment: @- refers to the usage in Sean's answer (piping btext into | curl --data @- instead of writing it using a $(subshell)). The >~50kb limit is what I assume to be the maximum size of a bash command vel alii.