# How to get success count, failure count and failure reason when testing rest webservices from file using shell script

Tags: windows, batch-file, curl, git-bash

Hi i am testing web services using shell script by having multiple if condition, with the shell script coding i am getting success count, failure count and failure reason

```
success=0
failure=0

if curl -s --head --request DELETE http://localhost/bimws/delete/deleteUser?email=pradeepkumarhe1989@gmail.com | grep "200 OK" > /dev/null; then 
  success=$((success+1))
else
echo "DeleteUser is not working"$'\r' >> serverLog.txt
  failure=$((failure+1))
fi

if curl -s --head  --request GET http://localhost/bimws/get/getUserDetails?email=anusha4saju@gmail.com | grep "200 OK" > /dev/null; then 
  success=$((success+1))
else
 curl -s --head  --request GET http://localhost/bimws/get/getUserDetails?email=anusha4saju@gmail.com > f1.txt
 echo "getUserDetails is not working"$'\r' >> serverLog.txt
  failure=$((failure+1))
fi

if curl -s -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json"  http://localhost/bimws/post/addProjectLocationAddress -d '{"companyid":"10","projectid":"200","addresstypeid":"5","address":"1234 main st","city":"san jose","state":"CA","zip":"989898","country":"United States"}' | grep "200 OK" > /dev/null; then 
  success=$((success+1))
else
echo "addProjectLocationAddress is not working"$'\r' >> serverLog.txt
  failure=$((failure+1))
fi

echo $success Success
echo $failure failure
```

but i am looking forward to test the web services from a file like i have file called web_services.txt which contains all my web services using shell script how do i execute and success count, failure count and failure reason

**web_services.txt**

All are different calls delete,get and post

```
http://localhost/bimws/delete/deleteUser?email=pradeepkumarhe1989@gmail.com


http://localhost/bimws/get/getUserDetails?email=anusha4saju@gmail.com



http://localhost/bimws/post/addProjectLocationAddress -d '{"companyid":"10","projectid":"200","addresstypeid":"5","address":"1234 main st"
,"city":"san jose","state":"CA","zip":"989898","country":"United States"}'
```

Comment: use -w to write the http exit code to file, then count the ones that are not successful and echo it.

Comment: i am new to this.. i didn't get you explain me in detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your current code does not correctly deal with empty lines. You need to skip those.

Your lines already contain shell commands. Running curl on them makes no sense. Instead, you should evaluate these commands.

Then, you need to modify curl so that it reports whether the request was successful by adding `-f`:

```
FILE=D:/WS.txt
success=0
failure=0
while read LINE; do
    if test -z "$LINE"; then
        continue
    fi
    if eval $(echo "$LINE" | sed 's/^curl/curl -f -s/') > /dev/null; then 
        success=$((success+1))
    else
        echo $LINE >> aNewFile.txt
        failure=$((failure+1))
    fi
done < $FILE
echo $success Success
echo $failure failure
```

Comment: The above code works fine for a single line if my curl command is more than a single line, then second continued line counting as a failure count

Comment: if curl -s -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json"  http://localhost/bimws/post/addProjectLocationAddress -d '{"companyid":"10","projectid":"200","addresstypeid":"5","address":"1234 main st","city":"san jose","state":"CA","zip":"989898","country":"United States"}' | grep "200 OK" > /dev/null; then 
  success=$((success+1))
else
echo deleteUser is not working > aNewFile.txt
  failure=$((failure+1))
fi

Comment: At the time I answered, `WS.txt` did only contain single-line commands. If it contains multiple-line commands, a simple `read` loop won't do. Instead, you need to parse commands first, and then run the inner body of the loop in the above code. But that really is another, unrelated, problem.