# Executing php scripts without opening browser

Tags: web, hyperlink, upload, processing

I want to execute a php file located in my apache server on localhost/remote from Processing. But I want to do it without opening the browser. How can I do this. The php script just adds data to mysql database using values obtained from  GET request. Is this possible? Actually I tried using link("/receiver.php?a=1&b=2") but it opens a web page containing the php output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally such scripts must be generic so that it can be used as utility for both web and bash scripts, in-case you cannot change/modify script, then I would suggest to curl from terminal/bash script to make HTTP request to the given link.

Refer to this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14978657/2575725), as how to make request with CURL.

Comment: Thank you Arvind.