# curl - suppress stdout header display in C -popen(...) statement

Tags: c, popen

In a Linux C program, I call

```
FILE *fd = popen("curl ipecho.net/plain", "r");
fgets(buffer, BUFFER_CONTENTS_MAX, fd);
pclose(fd);
```

to store my machine's IP address into a buffer, and it returns just the IP address (plus some other stuff which I strip off). It works fine, but during the call, CURL echoes a header to stdout despite the "/plain" switch. How can I suppress the stdout output? The unwanted output winds up looking like:

> % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time
> Current
> Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed 100    11  100    11    0     0     86      0 --:--:-- --:--:--
> --:--:--    85

Comment: Consider the second answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7373752/how-do-i-get-curl-to-not-show-the-progress-bar and maybe use `curl --no-progress-meter ipecho.net/plain` or `curl -sS ipecho.net/plain`.

Comment: To be clear, the extra text you're seeing is output from `curl`, not http headers from ipecho.net

Comment: I would recommend using libcurl.

Comment: EdmCoff's two curl suggestions both worked beautifully. Thanks! ...makes sense that it's curl output and not an http header.